# What is the faster way to find the maximum along axis on a symetrical matrix in numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Suppose I have a symetrical numpy array as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

N = 10000
b = np.random.random_integers(-2000,2000,size=(N,N))
b_symm = (b + b.T)/2
```

what is the most efficient algorithm to find the maximum for each row ? (like np.amax(axis=1))

Comment: There's only one compiled tool for doing that in `numpy`.  Symmetry doesn't make a difference.

Comment: so the only one solution is np.amax ?